Why program crash when destroy QOffscreenSurface subclass?
I want to render textures offscreen by using QOffscreenSurface and QOpenglContext class.Here are my codes:
OffscreenRender.h
class OffscreenRender:public QOffscreenSurface,protected QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit OffscreenRender(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~OffscreenRender();
    void paint();
    GLuint* getTBO();
    QOpenGLContext *getCurrentContext(){return openGLContext;}
private:
    void initialGL();
private:
    bool glInitialized = false;
    QOpenGLContext *openGLContext = nullptr;
    GLuint proGen = 0,
    vaoGen = 0,
    vboGen = 0,
    tbo = 0,
    fbo = 0;
};

OffscreenRender.cpp
OffscreenRender::OffscreenRender(QObject *parent)
{
    setParent(parent);
    QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat;
    surfaceFormat.setMajorVersion(4);
    surfaceFormat.setMinorVersion(3);
    surfaceFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);

    openGLContext = new QOpenGLContext();
    openGLContext->setFormat(surfaceFormat);
    QOpenGLContext *share = QOpenGLContext::globalShareContext();
    openGLContext->setShareContext(share);

    if(openGLContext->create()){
        setFormat(surfaceFormat);
        create();
        if(!isValid())
            qDebug("Unable to create the Offscreen surface");
            initialGL();
    }
    else{
        qDebug("Unable to create the context");
    }
}

OffscreenRender::~OffscreenRender(){
    openGLContext->makeCurrent(this);
    if(glIsProgram(proGen)){
        glDeleteProgram(proGen);
    }
    if(glIsVertexArray(vaoGen)){
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&vaoGen);
    }
    if(glIsBuffer(vboGen)){
        glDeleteBuffers(1,&vboGen);
    }
    if(glIsTexture(tbo)){
        glDeleteTextures(1,&tbo);
    }
    if(glIsFramebuffer(fbo)){
        glDeleteFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
    }
    openGLContext->doneCurrent();
    if(openGLContext){
        delete openGLContext;
    }
}

void OffscreenRender::paint(){
    if(glInitialized){
        openGLContext->makeCurrent(this);
        glViewport(0, 0, 100, 100);
        glClearColor(1,0,1,1);
        glUseProgram(proGen);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoGen);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        openGLContext->doneCurrent();
    }
}

GLuint *OffscreenRender::getTBO(){return &tbo;}

void OffscreenRender::initialGL(){
    openGLContext->makeCurrent(this);
    if(!initializeOpenGLFunctions()){
        qDebug("Unable to initialize the functions");
        return;
    }
    proGen = loadShaders();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoGen);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoGen);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboGen);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboGen);
    int nBytes = sizeof(float) * 16;
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,nBytes,vertexCord,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA32F, 100, 100);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tbo, 0);
    openGLContext->doneCurrent();
    glInitialized = true;
}

This class will render a rectangle in the center of texture tbo after call OffscreenRender::paint().But in destroy function,when call delete openGLContext;,Qt report ASSERT: "d_1_0_Core->refs.load()" in file opengl\qopenglfunctions_4_3_core.cpp, line 93.After removing this delete call, program works well.I don't know the reason.

You need to have OpenGL context before you can load OpenGL functions. When destructor of OpenGL functions loader (QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core) is called, context must be still valid - this doesn't happen in your code, because:

constructors in the following order are called: QOffscreenSurface, QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core, OffscreenRender
context is created
functions are loaded
in destructor of OffscreenRender context is deleted
then default destructors of QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core and QOffscreenSurface are invoked

in point (5) constructor of QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core expects the context used when loading GL functions to be still valid, but it is not.
You can add data member of QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core then initialize it when you got OpenGL context and call any GL functions via this object. Then you can delete GL functions loader before deleting context.
